# Can you select optimal tile sizes per each rendering devise used in homogenous rendering Blender 3.6.0 Windows 10 x64?

Tags: rendering, tilesize, radeon-prorender-render-engine

1. The Auto Tile Size preference isn't available in Blender 3 and my rendering software isn't yet compatible with Blender 4. How can you determine an optimal tile size for a specific CPU and for specific GPUs?
2. I'm homogenizing  computation between a CPU , GPU1, and GPU2... is there any way to set specific, optimal tile sizes for each rendering device instead of making them each render the same tile size?

Comment: 1. Well, even if there still was an _Auto Tile Size_ feature, it never was optimized for specific hardware, it was a general setting like smaller tiles for CPU and larger tiles for GPU. I never used that for example, because by testing out different sizes myself I found better values than the automatic ones. And that's how you determine the optimal tile size for specific hardware: test it yourself. Have one or more scenes and render them with different tile sizes for CPU and GPU and see which ones render fastest. Of course this can vary from depending on the content of your scene as well.

Comment: 2. No, there is no built-in tool to set specific sizes for specific hardware. Don't know if somebody can come up with some python script to do this maybe...